# how to make a ComboBox predictive (AutoSelective) in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am populating the items of `ComboBox` from Database. Now I want to give `Combobox` a functionality such that, as soon as user type few letters or a word,  it automatically selects and displays the item containing those alphabets or words. Presently I have written following lines of code

```
Private Sub From1_Load(By val connection = New OledbConnection("Data Source")
con.Open()
cmd = New OledbCommand("SQL",con)
DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While DataReader.Read
ComboBox1.items.Add(DataReader(0))
End While
Con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following properties of the ComboBox before filling

```
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help Rocoso

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim reader1 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim strSQL As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.connect()
        Me.fillcombo()
    End Sub

    Sub connect()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\aswer\aswer\databee.accdb"
        conn.Open()
    End Sub

    Sub fillcombo()
        strSQL = "select * from Table1"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL
        cmd.Connection = conn
        reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (reader1.Read())
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader1("ID Number"))
        End While

        cmd.Dispose()
        reader1.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        strSQL = "select * from Table1 where id='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        Dim comnd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        comnd.CommandText = strSQL
        comnd.Connection = conn
        reader1 = comnd.ExecuteReader
        If (reader1.Read() = True) Then
            TextBox1.Text = (reader1("Name"))
        End If

        comnd.Dispose()
        reader1.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```